# removeListener scoped in a addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have this code, which triggers a translation on hovered cards and removes the event listener on all the cards if one of them had been clicked.

But the listeners are not removed and the cards continue to move.

For complicated reasons I have to do it this way and not with css.

```
static bindEvents() {
        const playableCards = Hand.cards.filter(card => card.isPlayable)
        playableCards.forEach(card => {
            let onMouseEnter = () => {
                card.triggerTranslate(true)
            }
            let onMouseLeave = () => {
                card.triggerTranslate(false)
            }
            card.imgElt.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter)
            card.imgElt.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave)
            card.imgElt.addEventListener('click', () => {
                playableCards.forEach((card) => {
                    card.imgElt.removeEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter)
                    card.imgElt.removeEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave)
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want to remove the `click` handler, too?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a **new** pair of handlers for **each card**, but then using only one card's handlers to try to remove the handlers from **all** elements. That won't work, because you've only attached that pair of handlers to *one* element.

One solution would be to remember the handlers in an array so you can remove them later. Something like this (see comments):

```
static bindEvents() {
    // Use a single click ahndler for all elements, since you want to
    // do the same thing for all of them.
    const onClick = () => {
        forRemoval.forEach(({imgElt, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave}) => {
            imgElt.removeEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
            imgElt.removeEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);
            imgElt.removeEventListener('click', onClick); // Maybe?
        });
    };
    // Add the handlers, get the info we'll need to remove them
    const forRemoval = Hand.cards
        .filter(card => card.isPlayable)
        .map(card => {
            const {imgElt} = card;
            const onMouseEnter = () => {
                card.triggerTranslate(true)
            };
            const onMouseLeave = () => {
                card.triggerTranslate(false)
            };
            imgElt.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
            imgElt.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);
            imgElt.addEventListener('click', onClick);
            return {imgElt, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave};
        });
}
```